# Phonegap run android not working

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova, ant, path

I'm trying to run an android application with phonegap, I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm having the following issue:

```
 quest@quest:~/my-app$ phonegap run android
    [phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
    [phonegap] using the local environment
    [phonegap] adding the Android platform...

    /home/quest/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at /home/quest/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (/home/quest/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /home/quest/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/home/quest/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/quest/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /home/quest/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/quest/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
   [error] /home/quest/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8

e/quest/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    quest@quest:~/my-app$ brew install ant

    Warning: ant-1.9.3 already installed
```

and Here is the PATH

```
        quest@quest:~/my-app$ echo $PATH
    /home/quest/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/quest/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/quest/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/quest
/adt-bundle/sdk/tools:/home/quest/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/home/quest/android-sdk-
linux/platform-tools:/home/quest/android-sdk-
linux/tools:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin
:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools:adt-
bundle/sdk/tools:/Downloads/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Downloads/adt-
bundle/sdk/tools:/Downloads/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-
bundle/sdk/tools:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/ant/bin:/home/quest/ant/bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your system path using following command

```
echo $PATH
```

and make sure your ant path is added. If not then add to path.

Comment: The PATH is added but still the same problem

Comment: Make sure with, open terminal and type ant if you have command not found error then you have to find correct path and set. After setting the path dont forget to close and reopen the terminal. Then only path will affect.

Comment: I got Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

Comment: have you added your SDK path ?/